# Failed to retrieve leader gateway and port

Tags: apache-flink, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to get to work JobManager HA in the context of a per-job YARN session using
the 1.0.0-rc3 from a few days ago and are having a problem concerning task managers with several
network interfaces.

After manually killing the job manager process, the jobmanager.log on the newly allocated
second job manager reads:

```
2016-03-02 18:01:09,635 WARN  Remoting                                                   
  - Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://flink@10.127.68.136:34811].
Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters.
Reason: Connection refused: /10.127.68.136:34811
2016-03-02 18:01:09,644 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.JobManagerRetriever    
  - Failed to retrieve leader gateway and port.
akka.actor.ActorNotFound: Actor not found for: ActorSelection[Anchor(akka.tcp://flink@10.127.68.136:34811/),
Path(/user/jobmanager)]
    at akka.actor.ActorSelection$$anonfun$resolveOne$1.apply(ActorSelection.scala:65)
    at akka.actor.ActorSelection$$anonfun$resolveOne$1.apply(ActorSelection.scala:63)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:67)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:82)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:58)
    at akka.dispatch.ExecutionContexts$sameThreadExecutionContext$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:74)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:110)
    at akka.dispatch.ExecutionContexts$sameThreadExecutionContext$.execute(Future.scala:73)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:267)
    at akka.actor.EmptyLocalActorRef.specialHandle(ActorRef.scala:508)
    at akka.actor.DeadLetterActorRef.specialHandle(ActorRef.scala:541)
    at akka.actor.DeadLetterActorRef.$bang(ActorRef.scala:531)
    at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemoteDeadLetterActorRef.$bang(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:87)
    at akka.remote.EndpointWriter.postStop(Endpoint.scala:561)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundPostStop(Actor.scala:475)
    at akka.remote.EndpointActor.aroundPostStop(Endpoint.scala:415)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.akka$actor$dungeon$FaultHandling$$finishTerminate(FaultHandling.scala:210)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.terminate(FaultHandling.scala:172)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.terminate(ActorCell.scala:369)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:462)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:279)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:231)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

where the IP not found is from the old job manager. So far, is this the expected behavior?

The problem then arises on a new task manager, which also tries to connect to the old job
manager unsuccessfully. The ZooKeeperLeaderRetrievalService starts cycling through the available
network interfaces, as can be seen in the relevant taskmanager.log:

```
2016-03-02 18:01:13,636 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderretrieval.ZooKeeperLeaderRetrievalService
 - Starting ZooKeeperLeaderRetrievalService.
2016-03-02 18:01:13,646 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.util.LeaderRetrievalUtils         
  - Trying to select the network interface and address to use by connecting to the leading
JobManager.
2016-03-02 18:01:13,646 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.util.LeaderRetrievalUtils         
  - TaskManager will try to connect for 10000 milliseconds before falling back to heuristics
2016-03-02 18:01:13,712 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.net.ConnectionUtils               
  - Retrieved new target address /10.127.68.136:34811.
2016-03-02 18:01:14,079 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.net.ConnectionUtils               
  - Trying to connect to address /10.127.68.136:34811
2016-03-02 18:01:14,082 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.net.ConnectionUtils               
  - Failed to connect from address 'task.manager.eth0.hostname.com/10.127.68.136': Connection
refused
2016-03-02 18:01:14,082 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.net.ConnectionUtils               
  - Failed to connect from address '/10.127.68.136': Connection refused
2016-03-02 18:01:14,082 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.net.ConnectionUtils               
  - Failed to connect from address '/10.120.193.110': Connection refused
2016-03-02 18:01:14,082 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.net.ConnectionUtils               
  - Failed to connect from address '/10.127.68.136': Connection refused
2016-03-02 18:01:14,083 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.net.ConnectionUtils               
  - Failed to connect from address '/127.0.0.1': Connection refused
2016-03-02 18:01:14,083 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.net.ConnectionUtils               
  - Failed to connect from address '/10.120.193.110': Connection refused
2016-03-02 18:01:14,083 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.net.ConnectionUtils               
  - Failed to connect from address '/10.127.68.136': Connection refused
2016-03-02 18:01:14,083 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.net.ConnectionUtils               
  - Failed to connect from address '/127.0.0.1': Connection refused
```

After five repetitions, the task manager stops trying to retrieve the leader and using the
HEURISTIC strategy ends up using  eth1 (10.120.193.110) from now on:

```
2016-03-02 18:01:23,650 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderretrieval.ZooKeeperLeaderRetrievalService
 - Stopping ZooKeeperLeaderRetrievalService.
2016-03-02 18:01:23,655 INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn                            
  - EventThread shut down
2016-03-02 18:01:23,655 INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper                             
  - Session: 0x25229757cff035b closed
2016-03-02 18:01:23,664 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager           
  - TaskManager will use hostname/address 'task.manager.eth1.hostname.com' (10.120.193.110)
for communication.
```

Following the new jobmanager is discovered and the taskmanager is able to register at the
jobmanager using eth1. The problem is that connections TO eth1 are not possible. So flink
should always use eth0. The exception we later see is:

```
java.io.IOException: Connecting the channel failed: Connecting to remote task manager + 'other.task.manager.eth1.hostname/10.120.193.111:46620'
has failed. This might indicate that the remote task manager has been lost.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.PartitionRequestClientFactory$ConnectingChannel.waitForChannel(PartitionRequestClientFactory.java:196)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.PartitionRequestClientFactory$ConnectingChannel.access$000(PartitionRequestClientFactory.java:131)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.PartitionRequestClientFactory.createPartitionRequestClient(PartitionRequestClientFactory.java:83)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.NettyConnectionManager.createPartitionRequestClient(NettyConnectionManager.java:60)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.consumer.RemoteInputChannel.requestSubpartition(RemoteInputChannel.java:115)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.consumer.SingleInputGate.requestPartitions(SingleInputGate.java:388)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.consumer.SingleInputGate.getNextBufferOrEvent(SingleInputGate.java:411)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.BarrierBuffer.getNextNonBlocked(BarrierBuffer.java:108)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamInputProcessor.processInput(StreamInputProcessor.java:175)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OneInputStreamTask.run(OneInputStreamTask.java:65)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:224)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:559)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

The root cause seems to be that network interface selection is still using the old jobmanager
location and hence is not able to choose the right interface. In particular, it seems that
iteration order over the network interfaces differs between the HEURISTIC and SLOW strategy,
which then leads to the wrong interface being selected.

Comment: Could you state more clearly what your problem is?

Comment: i was edited again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem should be fixed with the upcoming bug fix release `1.0.1`. Alternatively, you can also use for the moment the current `1.1-SNAPSHOT` version of Flink.